# Am I extracting these fields correctly using bitwise shift? (tag, index, offset)

Tags: c, caching, cpu, simulator, bit-shift

I am building a CPU cache emulator in C.  I was hoping you could tell me if I am extracting these fields correctly:

The **32-bit address** should be broken up as follows:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| tag (20 bits) | index (10 bits) | offset (2 bits) |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is my code to obtain the values for each:

```
void extract_fields(unsigned int address){

   unsigned int tag, index, offset;

   // Extract tag
   tag = address >> 12;

   // Extract index
   index = address << 20;
   index = index >> 22;

   // Extract offset
   offset = address << 30;
   offset = offset >> 30;

}
```

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you doing `tag = tag << 12`?

Comment: Oops, I guess that shouldn't be in there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your solution works, but it is often done a different way that is probably a bit more clear.

For your example:

```
// Shift off the lowest 12 bits, and mask off the higher ones
tag = (address >> 12) & 0xFFFFF; 

// Shift off the lowest 2 bits, and mask off the higher ones
index = (address >> 2) & 0x3FF;

// Shift off the lowest 0 bits, and mask off the higher ones
offset = (address >> 0) & 0x3;
```